# jQuery version 1.9.1. - Does html() execute external scripts?

Tags: jquery, html

I've researched this in the web excessively for days now.

http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#loading-and-running-scripts-inside-html-content

Reading this official doc, the answer to the above question is not clear to me.

Does anyone know for sure?

Thanks very much and kind regards

Comment: Easy enough to try it and see, surely? http://jsbin.com/abumif/2/edit

Comment: @Quentin thats not an **external** scipt. By external I'm guessing a script tag with a href?

Comment: .html() will execute script tags inside of the html you add. External scripts (using src="...") inside the html will only be executed if the src path is absolute

Comment: @Liam — Still trivial to test: http://jsbin.com/abumif/5/edit

Comment: You can see it (not) working on http://4nf.org/ .  If one traverses through the pages, e.g. the ads disappear.  This indicates to me, that html() does not currently execute the external scripts correctly.  Even though I'm using absolute paths!

It would be great if someone knew for sure, before I go about crafting a workaround.  Thanks!

Comment: @Quentin, has just proven it for you. It works!

Comment: Yes, thanks very much - looks very convincing!  However it doesn't work on 4nf.org for some strange reason (see previous comment).

Comment: In which case see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Alright Liam, point taken - but sometimes a link says a million words, and I don't have a clue how to narrow it down more...

Comment: Just to close this thread properly - Google Adsense has disclaimed, that it cannot handle Ajax properly!  It has nothing to do with html() not working.  Thanks once more to all of you!